# Execute non-blocking shell command with specified environment variables

Tags: ruby, cucumber, popen

I try to invoke shell command with specified environment variables set and redirect command's STDOUT to my program's STDOUT.

I tried:

```
IO.popen({'DISPLAY' => ':0.0'}, "cucumber"){ |f| STDOUT.puts f.gets }
```

But I get `Broken pipe` error. This error doesn't appear if there is no block `{ |f| STDOUT.puts f.gets }`

How can I redirect command's output to STDOUT?

Note: I've tried:

```
IO.popen({'DISPLAY' => ':0.0'}, "cucumber", out: STDOUT)
```

But it doesn't print anything to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using:

```
IO.popen([{'DISPLAY' => ':0.0'}, 'cucumber']) { |f| f.each { |line| print line } }
```